# I cant set 2 variables to - each other and equal a third variable in swift

Tags: swift

I cant set 2 variables to - each other and equal a third variable in swift
I'm trying to make var1 - var2 == var3 work in swift but I get `Result of operator '==' is unused` when I use `==`
and when I use `=` I get `Cannot assign to value: binary operator returns immutable value` this is the code I'm working on.

```
var pices1 = 1
var pices2 = 1
var warmup: Int = 60
var nexx: Int = 60

func logic() {
    if count  <  10 {
        warmup = 5
        count - warmup == nexx
        pices1 = 1
        pices2 = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the operands to `==` backwards.

Comment: @rmaddy I still get the error `Result of operator '==' is unused` which in turn means the var isn't being set

Comment: Pretty sure Swift doesn't use `==` to set variables.

Comment: And clearly you mean to use `=`, not `==`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` is for checking if two values are equal. `=` is for assigning a new value to a variable.

Just like when you define a new variable, the destination is on the left and the new value is on the right.

```
var warmup: Int = 60
```

In your case, you'll want the following.

```
nexx = count - warmup
```